# When .py file become executable it stop running and stuck

Tags: python, selenium, command-line, pyinstaller, undetected-chromedriver

So I have this simple python script (`main.py`):

```
import sys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import undetected_chromedriver as uc


def do_work():
    print(sys.argv)
    driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('http://www.cnn.com')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_work()
```

So this `.py` file works fine and I convert it to `exe` file using `pyinstallser`:

```
pyinstaller --onefile C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\proj\main.py
```

And when I try to run the `exe` file its look like it stuck at the print of my `arguments` and not started my `browser`.

This is the input:

```
C:\Users\raviv>C:\Users\raviv\dist\main.exe bla bla
```

And this is the output (all the last lines continue and it seems like dead lock...):

```
['C:\\Users\\myuser\\dist\\main.exe', 'bla', 'bla']
['C:\\Users\\myuser\\dist\\main.exe', '--multiprocessing-fork', 'parent_pid=15632', 'pipe_handle=732']
['C:\\Users\\myuser\\dist\\main.exe', '--multiprocessing-fork', 'parent_pid=16956', 'pipe_handle=736']
['C:\\Users\\myuser\\dist\\main.exe', '--multiprocessing-fork', 'parent_pid=7672', 'pipe_handle=736']
['C:\\Users\\myuser\\dist\\main.exe', '--multiprocessing-fork', 'parent_pid=17280', 'pipe_handle=728']
['C:\\Users\\myuser\\dist\\main.exe', '--multiprocessing-fork', 'parent_pid=12048', 'pipe_handle=716']
['C:\\Users\\myuser\\dist\\main.exe', '--multiprocessing-fork', 'parent_pid=18204', 'pipe_handle=728']
```

Comment: What is the `undetected_chromedriver` module? Can you cause the problem without using that?

Comment: Yes its a module, When I am using webdriver.Chrome instead of uc.Chrome this works but as I mentioned with the .py file this works fine

Comment: I did not ask "is it a module?" I asked "what module is it?". I mean: how is it defined? What should be installed in order to use it? Where does it come from?

Comment: Tis installed using pip install and this module Optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot services, the pyinstaller using --onefile install all the dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add freeze_support to the script because one of your imported modules is using multiprocessing under the hood.

Try this:

```
import sys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
freeze_support()


def do_work():
    print(sys.argv)
    driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('http://www.cnn.com')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_work()
```

It should work fine after that.